# Signals between sheets in DipTrace

Tags: cad, diptrace

Given multiple sheets in DipTrace, I am looking to do something like this:

[image: Sheet connectors as desired]

There are a few ways I've found by which I can do something *functionally* similar - if not identical, - but which are visually awkward, take more room, are slightly misleading, harder to follow, and/or just plain don't follow the convention I'm used to.  The following illustrates those:

[image: Various sheet connection methods possible in DipTrace]

Is there some way to have something roughly similar to my first illustration above, preferably without some painstaking per-instance effort?

Comment: Been a while since I used DipTrace, but isn't there a way to add a "net port" (I think it's called)? That should connect nets on both different sheets and the same sheet. Failing that, maybe bin DipTrace and switch to KiCad? (Only sort of kidding)

Comment: @uint128_t That's basically correct.  You can rename built-in net ports to make them unique.  Unfortunately, as illustrated on pins 2, 3, and 4 above, the options for formatting these aren't great.  Custom components might be able to circumvent this, but not all that easily.

Comment: @uint128_t, a year or two ago I would have baulked at your suggestion to switch to KiCad (I'm a long-time DipTrace fanboy), but the recent massive hike in the price of DipTrace has me agreeing with you :)  I'm lucky that I have a pro copy of DT2.4 from back when it wasn't obscenely expensive.  I bet DT fans that don't own a pro copy are pretty bummed about it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own connector. Seriously. In component editor, preferably Discrete Schematic, Component > Add New to Library.

[image: Creating your own port connector]

Draw a port connector that you're use to. Make sure that the Part Type is Net Port.

In your schematic editor, add your components. Make sure to change the type of your connector to the same port that you want. For instance, I have two different types of connector: SIGNAL and CLOCK. The two SIGNAL ports connected to two different resistors, and a CLOCK port connected to a third resistor. When highlighting the trace to one of the resistors connected to SIGNAL, the entire port is highlighted. (Not shown is the label of the netport, which is both Net 0.)

As long as you change the names of the netport, you can have as many as you'd like. Unfortunately you'll have to at least once create it. (But it isn't so bad. It took me less than a minute.) The positive is that you can create your own custom netports. It doesn't have to look like this. Maybe you can have connector netport-- I.e. 12-pin header-- that spans a few pages, and you can connect to that connector instead.

[image: Custom netport in your schematic editor]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't strictly answer the question exactly as stated, so I'm not going to mark this as the answer, but I'll post what I've found as a satisfactory approach.

Basically, I adapted my style a bit more to the capabilities and omissions of the program.

I am used to the traditional use of busses to carry signals that are homogeneous except in magnitude, such as data lines, address lines, IRQs, etc.  There is, however, nothing to say they have to be limited to that schema.

This is a sheet I'm working on which is one of several sheets in the power supply/distribution section of a bigger project:

[image: Sample of using a bus for random related lines]

I decided to create a bus called PSU for the lines related to this section which would be needed between sheets.  Given clear enough names for the lines going into the bus, it's not particularly hard to understand.

One unexpected benefit arises when having to use the same line on opposite ends of the sheet.  I might typically have avoided (maybe needlessly) multiple instances of a sheet connector on a single sheet for fear of confusion.  With a bus, it's more visually obvious that you might have a line on it routed to several places, thus I've done that here for several lines.